# What is the difference between Satipatthana and Vipassana?

Tags: vipassana, satipatthana, meditation-mindfulness

In short, if i practice Vipassana meditation does it means i practice Satipatthana?

Comment: This topic was also discussed here: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/what-exactly-differentiates-vipassana-from-samatha-meditation

Answer (score 6):

Satipatthana is the name of the actual practice, and Vipassana is the name of the quality of clearly seeing reality which Satipatthana produces.

Comment: `Satipatthana is the name of the actual practice` Thanks a lot.  Could you kindly explain what is the `actual practice`? Do you mean the practice of Vipassana meditation?

Answer (score 4):

Vipassana itself is True Awareness, **clear-seeing presence in the moment absent of wandering thoughts.**
There is no Awakening without some success in Vipassana practice.
Continued Vipassana practice aka True Awareness, results in Complete Enlightenment.
Buddhism is really that simple and that's why the Buddha said "Mindfulness is liberation"!

Satipatthana is merely a *pathway* (or meditation method) for Vipassana training.
Another pathway would be Anapanasati (breathing meditation).
These are the two best paths and have sutras and many commentaries worth reading explaining how to construct that pathway.

In reality though all paths are the same and you will understand this after developing fluency over how to practice various meditation methods.

Comment: `Satipatthana is a something for Vipassana training` Thanks a lot. Could you kindly explain what is the `something`? An example maybe?

Comment: i was trying to keep it super simple because it really is. i rephrased it as "pathway" in original answer

Answer (score 2):

satipatthana = vipassana.

Vipassana is the meditation practice that follows the teachings of the Satipatthana Sutta (MN 22).

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about Anapanasati? Is it Satipatthana?

Comment: Yes. Anapanasati is mentioned in the Satipatthana Sutta as the 1st meditation object of the body (kayanupassana - 1st foundation of mindfulness).

Comment: It's questionable whether the satipatthana sutta was really by the Buddha or just a later addition. It is just a collection of meditations without any instructions. Please watch this: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MKL1arphx9A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Buddha first taught Vipassana meditation just after delivering Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta, when setting the Wheel of Dhamma in motion, to Pañcavaggiyas (five disciples - Kondanna, Bhaddiya, Vappa, Mahanama and Assaji).

Later Buddha delivered Satipatthana how to practice Vipassana in details.

Answer (score 0):

Satipatthana is the establishing of awareness, which can be achieved by Vipassana meditation.

Source: from [the discourse summaries book by S.N Goenka](http://www.saraniya.com/books/meditation/SN_Goenka-The_Discourse_Summaries.pdf):

[image]

[image]